# Suzuki Swift Bad Idle

Tags: rough-idle, suzuki, idle, swift

I am having trouble with my Suzuki swift`s bad idle 2009 (Engine M13A - Transmission Manual ).

The original problem was when i left the clutch in first gear to start from a stand still the rpm dropped from 700 to like 400 and the car used to stall most of the time. If the ac was on the idle rpm were around 900 and it was much easier to start from a stand still. My mechanic told me to have the clutch replaced and throttle body serviced(300$).

the problem that has occurred after the clutch and throttle body job is I am getting a check engine light and a bad idle only if the ac is off rpm swing between 1200-600 . if the ac is on the rpm are steady at 950.

I checked for vacuum leaks and could not find one.

I took the car to the dealer-ship the OBD scanning tool gave a code P0134(o2 sensor) but they said that the purge valve(90$+50$) is bad.

now I don`t know if I should spend the extra money or there is there some thing else wrong with the car and my original problem of the car dropping rpm when starting from a stand still is still there

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Do you not use gas when setting off with the clutch in your car? If you don't use gas whilst slipping the clutch, you're almost CERTAIN to stall without very fine clutch control. This can really, really damage your clutch if you keep using only the clutch to set off. The RPMs when you're setting off should be raised using the gas pedal to about 1.2k-1.5k depending on situation.

"my original problem of the car dropping rpm when starting from a stand still is still there"
The RPMs will ALWAYS drop when you're setting off. Watch a video on YouTube on how to set off in a manual car using clutch control. When the clutch rubs on the pressure plate and flywheel, that's trying to match the stationary clutch plate to the engine's rotating flywheel speed. This means that the flywheel rubbing against something is causing friction, making it harder for it to spin, slowing it down. This increase in friction causes the clutch plate to spin, this being attached to the gearbox which is attached to the wheels. The friction has to get to be enough that the spinning force (or the torque) will move the weight of a car. That's a lot of power required to do something like that.

Sounds like the bad idle is caused by that O2 sensor. Get this replaced and the purge valve and the idling should be normal.

Your original 'problem' sounds like user error. Use the gas pedal to raise the RPM before you raise the clutch. It sounds like you're trying to use the clutch to move the car using the engine's idle RPM. That WILL damage your clutch, and cause a LOT of stalls.

Comment: I guess the way I wrote the question makes me look like a bad driver. I have been driving manual since forever. I wrote the question here because i was certain that something is wrong with my car just don`t know what . I do exactly the things above on my friends swift and dads lancer and they launch smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you need to adjust the clutch cable, but I would have hoped this would have been done as part of the clutch replacement?  Once you can confirm or deny if this has been done, I *may* be able to help further.

Is it difficult to get into gear when stationary?  If you put the car into 5th when stationary with the clutch down does the engine drop in the same way?

Some of the issues you have mentioned may not be connected with each other.